# Pagination of reocords using MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

Tags: airflow

My workflow is:

1. I'm getting the max order id that we currently have from the Variable `LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID`
2. I'm getting the max `order_id` in the `MySQL` database
3. import orders between `LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID`  to the value in the `xcom` of `MySQL` using `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`

So far so good and this works well.

However the problem is when the gap between the value is too big. It can be `500K` orders. It's impossible to import that many records at once.

The `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` has the ability to break the file saved on storage into chunks with `approx_max_file_size_bytes` but it does not have the ability to chunk the query itself.

Basicly what I want to do is to use something like paging for the query. If
`xcom_order_id - LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID > 50K` then break the query for up to 50K rows meaning that I need to create operators dynamically.

This is what I tried to do:

```
LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID = Variable.get("last_order_id_imported")

start_task_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)

def chunck_import(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom = int(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_max_order_id_2_months_ago'))
    current = int(LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID)
    if xcom - current < 50000:
        num_pages = 1
    else:
        num_pages = int((xcom / current) + 1)
    logging.info(xcom)
    logging.info(current)
    for i in range(1, num_pages + 1):  #for 1 page its range(1,2)
        start = LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID * i
        end = start + 50000
        if end > xcom:
            end = xcom
        import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
            task_id='import_orders_and_upload_to_storage_orders-{}'.format(i),
            mysql_conn_id='mysqlcon',
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id='googlecon',
            provide_context=True,
            approx_max_file_size_bytes=100000000,
            sql='select * from e.orders where orders_id between {{ params.start }} and {{ params.end }}',
            params={'start': start, 'end': end},
            bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
            filename=file_name_orders,
            dag=dag)


chunck_import_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='chunck_import',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=chunck_import,
    dag=dag)

start_task_op >> get_max_order_id_2_months_ago >> chunck_import_op
```

This has no errors and it run successfuly but it does nothing.

The value in `XCOM` is correct. but the `chunck_import_op`  doesn't do anything. Also I don't see the dynamically created `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` in my UI:

[image]

Also notice the `print num_pages` I also don't see the value in the log.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, an operator cannot modify the DAG its in. Since you can only pull xcom in an operator execution, I would suggest that instead of adding the operator to the DAG, you instead, at the end of the loop setting up operators, within the loop, call:

```
import_orders_op.pre_execute(**kwargs)
import_orders_op.execute(**kwargs)
```

It's a bit kludgy since all the log output will be in the task `chunck_import` which you might want to rename logically for yourself (`import_in_chunks`?), but it *should* work, and your DAG won't change the exactly number of tasks per run.

Alternatively, and I think this is even kludgier, assume a maximum number of chunks, setup a pair of `ShortCircuitOperator` and `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` for each range of chunk based. The `ShortCircuitOperator` should check if the starting range of the chunk is valid and run the sql 2 gcs op if it is, or short circuit if not.

The better approach would be to subclass the MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator into a PagedMySqlToGCSOperator, over-riding `execute`, `_query_mysql`, and `_write_local_data_files`. It's more work though.

Comment: My problem is quite simple actually. Each MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator runs a different `WHERE`. I need a way to provide these wheres to the operator and create a single MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator  that runs all of them or create multipule MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator  as the number of where statments.

Comment: So the first of my two suggestions, to execute each differently ranged `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` within the `PythonOperator` should work for you.